# XSLT injects text between nodes

Tags: xslt, saxon

Given input file

```xml
<propertyDescriptor>
  <name repeat="1">enable_decline_rule</name>
  <description>text</description>
  <type>BOOLEAN</type>
  <defaultValue>false</defaultValue>
  <dependentPropertyDescriptors>
    <dependentPropertyDescriptor>
      <value>true</value>
      <propertyDescriptor>
        <name repeat="1">decline_rule_identifier</name>
        <description>This is some random text.</description>
        <type>STRING</type>
      </propertyDescriptor>
    </dependentPropertyDescriptor>
  </dependentPropertyDescriptors>
</propertyDescriptor>
```

and stylesheet

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" standalone="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- match the tree that needs to be repeated -->
    <xsl:template match="propertyDescriptor[name='enable_decline_rule']">
        <xsl:call-template name="block-generator">
            <xsl:with-param name="N" select="1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="block-generator">
        <xsl:param name="N"/>
        <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
        <xsl:if test="$N >= $i">
            <!-- generate a block -->
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:call-template name="new-descriptor">
                    <xsl:with-param name="N" select="$i"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:copy>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="block-generator">
                <xsl:with-param name="N" select="$N"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="new-descriptor">
        <xsl:param name="N"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="node()">
            <xsl:call-template name="append_name">
                <xsl:with-param name="N" select="$N"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="append_name" >
        <xsl:param name="N"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- tags with a repeat attribute get a _N -->
            <xsl:when test="$N >= 1 and @repeat">
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>_<xsl:value-of select="$N"/>
                </name>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$N >= 1">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                        <xsl:call-template name="append_name">
                            <xsl:with-param name="N" select="$N"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get this output

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<propertyDescriptor>
    <name>enable_decline_rule_1</name>
    <description>text</description>
    <type>BOOLEAN</type>
    <defaultValue>false</defaultValue>
    <dependentPropertyDescriptors>
        truedecline_rule_identifierThis is some random text.STRING
        <dependentPropertyDescriptor>
            true
            <value>true</value>
            <propertyDescriptor>
                decline_rule_identifier
                <name>decline_rule_identifier_1</name>
                <description>This is some random text.</description>
                <type>STRING</type>
            </propertyDescriptor>
        </dependentPropertyDescriptor>
    </dependentPropertyDescriptors>
</propertyDescriptor>
```

But remove the `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` tag and the output is clean.
I also get corrupted data if I use net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:12.0

UPDATE

To clarify my requirements, I have to duplicate the propertyDescriptor element (which element to duplicate by how many times is fed to the xslt as 2 params. I hardcoded these to simply the problem)

It not enough to simply duplicate propertyDescriptor elements, the name must also be unique. Expected output for 2 counts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<propertyDescriptor>
    <name>enable_decline_rule_1</name>
    <description>text</description>
    <type>BOOLEAN</type>
    <defaultValue>false</defaultValue>
    <dependentPropertyDescriptors>
        <dependentPropertyDescriptor>
            <value>true</value>
            <propertyDescriptor>
                <name>decline_rule_identifier_1</name>
                <description>This is some random text.</description>
                <type>STRING</type>
            </propertyDescriptor>
        </dependentPropertyDescriptor>
    </dependentPropertyDescriptors>
</propertyDescriptor>
<propertyDescriptor>
    <name>enable_decline_rule_2</name>
    <description>text</description>
    <type>BOOLEAN</type>
    <defaultValue>false</defaultValue>
    <dependentPropertyDescriptors>
        <dependentPropertyDescriptor>
            <value>true</value>
            <propertyDescriptor>
                <name>decline_rule_identifier_2</name>
                <description>This is some random text.</description>
                <type>STRING</type>
            </propertyDescriptor>
        </dependentPropertyDescriptor>
    </dependentPropertyDescriptors>
</propertyDescriptor>
```

Comment: It helps to say what output you expect. Your stylesheet is outputting exactly what your XSLT code tells it to output, so it's hard to correct your code without knowing what output you actually wanted.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I ran the code without the xsl:strip-space, and the output is different, but looks equally "unclean" to me. So it's very hard to help you without knowing what your transformation is trying to achieve. It's not helped by the fact that your code seems pretty convoluted, which makes reverse engineering the requirements especially difficult.

Comment: You might want to rethink your approach and use template matching and apply-templates instead of named templates and call-template; also think clearly when you need/want to process any kind of nodes (e.g. element nodes, text nodes, ..) with e.g. `node()` or perhaps only element nodes with e.g. `*`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen my colleague is working on an alternative. It would be nice to know why we get different results with different engines though, and when adding strip-spaces

Comment: Then explain exactly which result you get for one engine that you identify precisely and which different result you get for another engine that also identify precisely. It is not clear which engine and processor you use for "this output" and what kind of "corrupted data" you get with Saxon 12.

Comment: @caduceus Thanks for clarifying the requirement. Sorry, I'm not going to attempt to debug your code, it's far too contorted; much easier to rewrite it as Martin has done. It's entirely reasonable that `xsl:strip-space` should affect the result, since your logic iterates sometimes over child nodes and sometimes over child elements.

Comment: I think the instruction that's generating the unwanted text is probably the `<xsl:value-of select="node()"/>` in the second branch of the `append_name` template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems with XSLT 3 you can use the `to` operator e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="propertyDescriptor[name/@repeat]">
    <xsl:for-each select="(0 to name/@repeat)!current()">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="copy">
        <xsl:with-param name="id" select="position()" tunnel="yes"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode name="copy" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template mode="copy" match="name[@repeat]">
    <xsl:param name="id" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:copy>{.}_{$id}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce the output

```
<propertyDescriptor>
   <name>enable_decline_rule_1</name>
   <description>text</description>
   <type>BOOLEAN</type>
   <defaultValue>false</defaultValue>
   <dependentPropertyDescriptors>
      <dependentPropertyDescriptor>
         <value>true</value>
         <propertyDescriptor>
            <name>decline_rule_identifier_1</name>
            <description>This is some random text.</description>
            <type>STRING</type>
         </propertyDescriptor>
      </dependentPropertyDescriptor>
   </dependentPropertyDescriptors>
</propertyDescriptor>
<propertyDescriptor>
   <name>enable_decline_rule_2</name>
   <description>text</description>
   <type>BOOLEAN</type>
   <defaultValue>false</defaultValue>
   <dependentPropertyDescriptors>
      <dependentPropertyDescriptor>
         <value>true</value>
         <propertyDescriptor>
            <name>decline_rule_identifier_2</name>
            <description>This is some random text.</description>
            <type>STRING</type>
         </propertyDescriptor>
      </dependentPropertyDescriptor>
   </dependentPropertyDescriptors>
</propertyDescriptor>
```

from the input

```
<propertyDescriptor>
  <name repeat="1">enable_decline_rule</name>
  <description>text</description>
  <type>BOOLEAN</type>
  <defaultValue>false</defaultValue>
  <dependentPropertyDescriptors>
    <dependentPropertyDescriptor>
      <value>true</value>
      <propertyDescriptor>
        <name repeat="1">decline_rule_identifier</name>
        <description>This is some random text.</description>
        <type>STRING</type>
      </propertyDescriptor>
    </dependentPropertyDescriptor>
  </dependentPropertyDescriptors>
</propertyDescriptor>
```